# Collect certain data from multiple worksheets in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need a VBA code to collect data from multiple worksheets in Excel.

I'm using the following code to collect all data from multiple worksheets in Excel:

```
Sub Combine()
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets.Add Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Combined"
   For I = 2 To Sheets.Count
        Set xRg = Sheets(1).UsedRange
        If I > 2 Then
            Set xRg = Sheets(1).Cells(xRg.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
        End If
        Sheets(I).Activate
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xRg
    Next
End Sub
```

Sometimes, the return data is varies due to some cells that have values (but it should be empty) which destroy the arrangement of the combined sheet.

How to modify above code to copy only a certain range, for example ($A$1:$L$51) or it can be defined on screen from the first sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```vb
Sub Combine()
    Const RNG_COPY As String = "A1:L51"
    Dim i As Long, xRg As Range, wsComb As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook, cDest As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'or ActiveWorkbook?
    Set wsComb = wb.Worksheets.Add(before:=wb.Sheets(1)) 'get a reference to the added sheet
    wsComb.Name = "Combined"
    Set cDest = wsComb.Range("A1")
    
    For i = 2 To wb.Sheets.Count
         With wb.Sheets(i).Range(RNG_COPY)
            .Copy cDest
            Set cDest = cDest.Offset(.Rows.Count) 'next paste destination
         End With
     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I test it once and it works. i'll test again on several sheets to confirm no bugs. Thanks